# Assigning an object in a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, assign

I have a bunch of corpus loaded into the R environment and I want to transform each one into a Term Document Matrix. I tried a combination of a `for` loop and `assign` command but it's not working and I can't figure out what is wrong.

I store the names of the corpus in the environment in a list:

```
bNames<-ls()
```

And make a named list of objects

```
corpus.n1<-mget(bNames)
> corpus.n1
$qB001
<<VCorpus (documents: 1, metadata (corpus/indexed): 0/0)>>

$qB002
<<VCorpus (documents: 1, metadata (corpus/indexed): 0/0)>>
....
```

The libraries and n-gram function

```
library(rJava) 
.jinit(parameters="-Xmx128g")
library(RWeka)
nGra2Tok <- function(x) NGramTokenizer(x, Weka_control(min = 2, max =2))
```

The kind of things I want to put into the loop:

```
tdm.n2.01<-TermDocumentMatrix(qB001,control=list(tokenize=nGram2Tok))
tdm.n2.02<-TermDocumentMatrix(qB002,control=list(tokenize=nGram2Tok))
tdm.n2.03<-TermDocumentMatrix(qB003,control=list(tokenize=nGram2Tok))
....
```

and the `TermDocumentMatrix` loop

```
for(i in corpus.n1){
  tdm.n2<-paste(i)
  assign(i, TermDocumentMatrix(tdm.n2,control=list(tokenize=nGram2Tok)))
}
```

The error I get:

```
Error in UseMethod("TermDocumentMatrix", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'TermDocumentMatrix' applied to an object of class "character"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `corpus.n1` is already a named list. If you want to apply the same function to all elements, you don't need a loop at all -- a simple `lapply` will do the job:

```
tdm.n2 <- lapply(corpus.n1, TermDocumentMatrix, control = list(...))
```

Note that the `control` parameter is passed to the `TermDocumentMatrix` function for each invocation. See `?lapply` and also `?mapply` for more detail.